# How to get DataGrid colum value when a button is clicked from inside DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I Have a **silverlight** DataGrid like below

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="DataGridDream" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"  >

        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns >
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding By}"   >

                </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" >

                </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="ButtonSave" Content="Take" Click="ButtonSave_Click">

                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and i have a Click event of the button inside DataGrid,

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Value = // Value of the UserId column when a button is clicked on that row
}
```

how to do that ?

Comment: I think you could try to bind the currently SelectedItem against an object in your code behind. After a click on the button, the row should be in a selected state, you can simply access the id of the user by checking the property against which you did the SelectedItem binding.

Comment: @Eisenhorn can you show me how to do that

Comment: ((Button)sender).DataContext should be the item the current data grid row is bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you value of `UserName` property of clicked row:

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string userName = (((Button)sender).DataContext as ModelClass).UserName;
}
```

***ModelClass** is where your property resides i.e. underlying source class for your bindings.*

Comment: the type or namespace name 'Model Class' could not be found it says

Comment: Yeah like i mentioned replace `ModelClass` with actual class where `UserName` property exists.

Comment: any article or book for learning about silverlight DataGrid and its events and everything ?

Comment: Links [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) and [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected item from the DataGrid try something like this:

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    var row = (int)DataGridDream.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: what values it loads into the row variable, i mean i have tow values binded, 'By' and 'UserName' , how to take one of those values ?

Comment: It depends on what type is in the column. You can cast it appropriately based on the type. Set a break point inside the click event and take a look at the DataGridDream.SelectedItem type.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the current row values as a dynamic object. You can access all the values in the grid row using that object.

The modified version of Mike Schwartz's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20975402/5407188) would be

```cs
    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic row = DataGridDream.SelectedItem;
    }
```

You can also obtain the row values as Rohit Vats [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978224/5407188). But by using the dynamic keyword you will not have to declare a Model class.

```cs
    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       dynamic row = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
    }
```

After that, you can access the UserName like this

```cs
    var UserName = row.UserName;
```